# Removing Date from Date/Time field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to select records where the start time is between 12:00 midnight and 5:00am using Access. I use this;

```
Sheet1.[Start Time] BETWEEN #00:00:00# AND #04:59:59#;
```

But it gives me zero results. I feel it's because "Start Time" is a date/Time field and displays the date before the time. I have tried formatting the field to be a Long Time field, but it keeps the date regardless. How do I remove the date from the field?

Answer (score 2):

`TimeValue(MyDate)` will give you just the time portion of a datetime field.